# Bind incoming integer value to mat-radio-button value in formgroup

Tags: angular, data-binding, radio-button, angular-material, formgroups

I am loading integer type values from a db to populate a formgroup's radio buttons. The radio-group only reads values if I convert the incoming integers to strings. How can make the mat-radio-group accept integer values?

I have tried changing `value="1"` to `[value]="1"` but that had no effect. The only reference to this I could find was an issue on the material2 github page [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10317)

HTML

```html
 <form class="mb-4" [formGroup]="wifiForm">
        <label id="wifi_available">Is working WiFi present on the property?</label>
        <mat-radio-group
          aria-labelledby="wifi_available"
          class="list-radio-group w-100 mb-4 mt-2"
          formControlName="wifi_available"
          name="wifi_available"
          fxLayout="column"
          required
        >
          <mat-radio-button class="list-radio-button" color="primary" [value]="1">Yes</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button class="list-radio-button" color="primary" [value]="2">No</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-error *ngIf="wifiForm.controls.wifi_available.hasError('required').required && wifiForm.controls.wifi_available.touched" class="error"
            >Required field</mat-error
          >
        </mat-radio-group>
...rest of form... 
</form>
```

Component

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.wifiForm = this.fb.group({
      wifi_available: ['', Validators.required],
      wifi_deadspots: ['', Validators.required],
      wifi_notes: [''],
    });
    this.orderId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.wifiData = this.route.snapshot.data['order_data']; <== WHERE DATA IS BROUGHT IN
    this.wifiForm.patchValue(this.wifiData); <== WHERE DATA IS PATCHED
  }
```

Values coming in from db [example]
{
wifi_available: 1,
wifi_deadspots: 1,
wifi_notes: 'Lorem bacon...'
}

I am expecting the mat-radio-buttons to be checked accordingly (if 1, then "Yes" checked). If I changed the db field type to VARCHAR the radio-buttons are checked as expected. If the db fields are INT (as they should be) then no radio-buttons are checked.

Comment: if you put '[]' to value, you are trying to bind it to 1; which makes no sense to it because if it's a radio button that expects a boolean, both 1 and 2 will become true (only 0 is considered false when taking numbers as booleans in js).

If you want to convert the integers to strings, try adding them to an empty string, that converts is, such as `'' + myDbNum`

Tell me if this helps u

Comment: If your incoming data is truly `{ wifi_available: 1, wifi_deadspots: 1, wifi_notes: 'Lorem bacon...' }` it should work with the code you have with using `[value]` Please recreate issue in stackblitz :)

Comment: Thank you both for your input.

Comment: Your link to the github issue helped me: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10317#issuecomment-371263760 .  In my case I also couldn't get the int to mat-radio-button binding working.  The solution was changing value="1" to [value]='1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added

`[checked]="wifiForm.value.wifi_available === true"`

to mat-radio-button (wifiForm treated the 1/0 as boolean) and this worked.

The I only needed to update the html

```html
<form class="mb-4" [formGroup]="wifiForm">
  <label id="wifi_available">Is working WiFi present on the property?</label>
  <mat-radio-group
          aria-labelledby="wifi_available"
          class="list-radio-group w-100 mb-4 mt-2"
          formControlName="wifi_available"
          name="wifi_available"
          fxLayout="column"
          required
        >
  <mat-radio-button class="list-radio-button" color="primary [checked]="wifiForm.value.wifi_available === true" value="1">Yes</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button class="list-radio-button" color="primary [checked]="wifiForm.value.wifi_available === false"value="0">No</mat-radio-button>

... </form>
```

This worked for other values in other components I was having the same issue with.